# Помогите разобраться с кодом в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Мне надо заполнить таблицу «Заявка» с ограничивающими условиями:

1. количество заявок — 1825; 2) раз в 3 дня подают 5 заявок.
   Я написал код, но он выдаёт следующую ошибку: Имя столбца или число предоставленных значений не соответствует определению таблицы. У меня не получается найти ошибку. Можете проверить и написать, что не так.[image: Код для заполнения таблицы]

Comment: Укажите в insert явно список столбцов в которые идет вставка. Скорее всего в ней не 4 столбца, сколько значений вы указали в values

Comment: В коде я правильно написал ограничения?

Comment: Я не вижу в коде никаких ограничений. От того что RlientID увеличивается в каждой строке на 5 ничего не меняется. ID клиентов видимо могут быть вообще произвольными. Да и внутренний begin без какого либо цикла или еще чего то выглядит странно

Comment: И кстати фразу "раз в 3 дня подают 5 заявок" можно толковать по разному: Как "за 3 дня в среднем 5 заявок", а тогда заявки есть каждый день, просто если в первый день было 2 заявки, то в оставшиеся 2 дня их может быть только 3. Или как то, что 5 заявок в один день, потом 4 дня пропускаем и опять 5 завявок

Comment: И что такое DateTableID то же несколько странно выглядит, когда речь о днях то в таблице обычно колонка типа date или datetime и дни тогда добавляются соотвествующими функциями.

Comment: DateTable это таблица с периодом (c 01.01.2019 по 31.12.2021). В таблицу входят столбцы дата, год, квартал, месяц, день, день недели и сезон (зима, весна, лето, осень).

Comment: Ограничение «раз в 3 дня подают 5 заявок» я придумал сам. Это означает, что через каждые 3 дня подают 5 заявок. Т.е. в течении 3 дней в сервис по сборке мебели никто не обращается, а на 4-ый день обращаются 5 клиентов и подают 5 заявок.